# Eclipse Javadocs: How to *easily* create @see links?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-jdt

I often want to use @see when writing classes & methods but I usually end up not doing so because it's so annoying trying to write out @see links by hand.

Is there some easy way to do this, built into Eclipse JDT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use content assist and it will automatically insert references for you. Depending on what you need exactly, you may be able to save some time by adding a code template by going to Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Templates.